Is there a way to register multi terms' descriptions or an eye-catching image by uploading CSV?
How to bulk register descriptions and featured images for multiple terms set in a custom taxonomy?
I was looking into using the following plugins, but it seems that Really Simple CSV Importer can only upload post data, so it didn’t work out as expected:

Advanced Custom Fields
Really Simple CSV Importer

Additionally, I would like to be able to specify IDs or similar information to update the data for terms that are already registered in WordPress.
CSV sample
